# Returning from nested functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function outer() {
    $(['hi', 'there']).each(function(idx, e) {
        console.log(e);
        return;
    });
    alert("I don't want to be called");
}

function outer() {    
    $.get('http://test.com', function (data) {
        console.log(data)
        return; // I want to terminate the entire outer() function here.
    });
    alert("I don't want to be called");
}
```

What's the convention of breaking out of nested functions in cases like this? When using `for` loops, returning inside them terminates the entire function that encloses them. However, since `$.each()` is an individual function call, returning from it only ends itself, not the outer function. I could simply `return` twice, once inside and once outside in that case, but I am not sure how I would deal with `$.ajax()` because it is necessary to terminate the function only when I get a successful response.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but try `return false;`

Comment: you can't do that because of the async nature of ajax

Comment: Short answer: you can't. It's possible to have a workaround of sorts with the first example, but `$.get` is asynchronous, and `outer` will have returned before the inner function is even called.

Comment: This is not called nested function. It is callback function. Google it.

Comment: Your returns are inside callback functions for the jQuery constructs, you could put a return command before the jQuery selector to return from the main function also.

Comment: Or you can set a boolean insite your inner function and check for its value before continuing your `outer()`

Comment: @zsong: It's still a nested function. They're not mutually exclusive terms.

Comment: I am glad I asked :) Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a summary of how it all works.

**.each()**

```
return true;  // skips to the next iteration of .each()
return false; // exits the .each() loop
```

In short there's no way of breaking out of the function containing `.each()` in a single statement.

**$.get()**

```
return [true|false]; // makes no sense at all.
```

As the return in `$.get()` does not get executed until the ajax call is complete, it wont serve much purpose. Even when you make a synchronous ajax call, a return statement in the success callback still does not do anything substantive. **Think of a return from a function as a value to be assigned to the calling statement.**

What's making it necessary to break out of your functions?

Answer (score 1):

For `$.each()`, you can stop the iteration with `return false;` in the callback, as described in the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

This won't return from the calling function, but you can set a flag and test it in the outer function.

If you want an easy way to return from the outer function from inside the loop, you're better off with a simple `for` loop:

```
var array = [ 'hi', 'there' ];
for( var i = 0;  i < array.length;  ++i ) {
    var e = array[i];
    console.log(e);
    return;
}
alert("I don't want to be called");
```

For `$.get()`, you should add some `console.log()` calls to your code and observe the order in which they are called:

```
function outer() {
    console.log( 'in outer before $.get is called' );
    $.get('http://test.com', function (data) {
        console.log( 'inside $.get callback' );
    });
    console.log( 'in outer after $.get returns' );
}
```

Now what you'll notice is the order of the log messages:

```
in outer before $.get is called
in outer after $.get returns
inside $.get callback
```

See how the callback is the last thing? It's called *after* the `outer` function finishes. Therefore, there is nothing this callback can do to prevent the rest of `outer` from executing.

So you need to think some more about what you need to do and figure out a different way to accomplish it.

Comment: Hi Michael. Thanks! I checked the document and it seems it's impossible to break out of the outer function because `return false` simply terminates `$.each()` function.

Comment: Yeah, I misread what you were asking, sorry! You should just use a simple `for` loop instead of `$.each()` to make it easy to do this; I updated the answer with that...

Answer (score 0):

If you use $.ajax() instead of the short hand $.get(), it is possible to specify that it be executed synchronously.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://test.com',
  success: function (data) {
  },
  async: false
});
```

Typically, when you want to make a decision based on the return value of a function you have it return a value and then use a conditional statement to determine what happens next.

Comment: `async: false` has some very undesirable consequences. In some browsers, if your server is slow or fails to respond, it will lock up not only the current browser tab/window but *all* browser windows. It is recommended only as a very last resort - it's much better to write correct asynchronous code.